# How to align these two elements inside a div

Tags: html, css

I am having a little trouble aligning two elements inside a div (the quote and the arnold pic).

Here is what it looks like: [image]

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="quote">     
        <p id="tagline-quote">"As a personal fitness trainer, I&#039;m asked on a weekly basis where the best place to buy supplements is, and my answer is always bodybuilding.com"</p>

        <img id="q-image" alt="" src="http://www.cheapestsupplementsonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/arnold_schwarzenegger.jpg"></img>
    </div> <!-- end #quote -->
```

Here is the css:

```
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    width: 960px;
}

#quote {
    padding: 60px 400px 20px 13px;
    text-align: center;
}


p#tagline-quote {
    color: #777676;
    font-family: Georgia,serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #FFFFFF;
}

#q-image{
}
```

Comment: how do you want to place them ?

Comment: The quote on the left and the pic to the right of it

Comment: So this is where Arnold gets his stuff from?

Comment: @SalmanA It's not well known, but yeah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a textbook "css floats 101" question. *Oh, wait, I thought that was original but that's exactly what [the article on alistapart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-floats-101/) is called.* You can position the image inside the quote/paragraph and float it right - that's pretty much what the floats were made for before semantic layouts took over :)

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="quote" class="clearfix">
        <img id="q-image" alt="" src="http://www.cheapestsupplementsonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/arnold_schwarzenegger.jpg" />        
        <p id="tagline-quote">&#8220;As a personal fitness trainer, I&#039;m
        asked on a weekly basis where the best place to buy supplements is,
        and my answer is always bodybuilding.com&#8221;</p>
    </div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

For CSS, I've thrown out some of the original padding :

```
#q-image{
    float:right;
    /*add some margin so that there is space between text and photo*/
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

Now the issue that you were having with KodeKreachor's code was seemingly incorrectly "garbling" the divs below and you probably saw the quote container looking shorter than it should be. The workaround is using a "clearfix" that expands the parent container so that the floated element can fit inside. Remove it from the code and see how the (temporarily) highlighted container acts.

On a side note... try adding more paragraphs and move the image into one of them. Now that "odd" behaviour makes perfect sense - paragraphs start flowing nicely around that floated image without massive gaps.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EvdV8/ Also: proper quotes. Also: img is a *self-closing* element so original markup was not valid.

Comment: I read the entire article you posted above. Extremely useful and thorough. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about side-by-side, you use a combination of "float: left;" and "display: inline-block" to force them next to each other.

```
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    width: 960px;
}

#quote {
    padding: 60px 400px 20px 13px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
}


p#tagline-quote {
    color: #777676;
    font-family: Georgia,serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #FFFFFF;
    position:relative;
    width:400px;
    display: inline-block;

}

#q-image{
    position:relative;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: this... is not what inline-blocks are for

Comment: I'll concede that one or the other should be used, however I don't see anything wrong with using inline-block to flexibly display block items side-by-side. It allows you to easily adjust the height of each, so positioning where the text aligns with the image is simple. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Inline-blocks are originally used to, well, position block elements inline with text (i.e. in the middle of the text). Bigger issues come out of its handling of vertical alignment and especially whitespace like shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/BxAcW/ - there are better explanations available, like http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/